# How can i compare 2 tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

i have a table named **hotel** with 2 columns named : **hotel_name** , **hotel_price**

```
hotel_name | hotel_price
hotel1     |     5
hotel2     |     20
hotel3     |     100
hotel4     |     50
```

and another table named **city** that contains the column : **city_name** , **average_prices**

```
city_name | average_prices
paris     |      20
london    |      30
rome      |      75
madrid    |      100
```

I want to find which hotel has a price that's more expensive than average prices in the cities.For example i want in the end to find something like this:

```
hotel_name | city_name   
hotel3     |   paris      --hotel3 is more expensive than the average price in paris
hotel3     |  london      --hotel3 is more expensive than the average price in london etc.
hotel3     |   rome
hotel4     |   paris
hotel4     |  london
```

(I found the hotels that are more expensive than the average prices of the cities)

Any help would be valuable thank you .

Comment: Do you need this query/function often? If not I would use external code and just fetch all related DB data (if the table is very large in batches) and compare them by code not directly inside the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple join is all that is needed. Typically tables are joined on a defined relationship (PK/FK) but there is nothing requiring that.  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fb98b01a88d78bbc9288413aab7c3ed6).

```
select h.hotel_name, c.city_name
  from hotels h 
  join cities c
    on h.hotel_price > c.average_prices;
```

However, while you can get the desired results, it's pretty meaningless. You cannot tell whether a particular hotel is even in a given city.